# Why does Grails ignore this particular String parameter unless I bind it explicitly?

Tags: mysql, grails, data-binding

I have a class `Item`:

```
class Item {
  String title
  String description
  String linkText
  String linkUrl

  static constraints = {
    title blank: false
    description blank: false
    linkText blank: false
    linkUrl blank: false, url: true
}
```

and when I attempt to save a new instance of `Item` using

```
def itemInstance = new Item(params)
itemInstance.save()
```

I get a validation error:

```
Property [linkText] of class [class Item] cannot be null
```

I have two problems with this:

1. `linkText` is right there in the form, in a `<g:textField>` with `name="linkText"`. Why is it not being bound to `itemInstance`? If I print out the params before a `save()`, I get them all, including `linkText`, but if I then print out the properties of the pre-saved `itemInstance` when I have constructed it from those params, `linkText` on the instance is `null`. I can change my saving code to

   ```
   def itemInstance = new Item(params)
   itemInstance.linkText = params.linkText
   ```

   and it will be saved without any problems and use `params.linkText`. But why should I have to do that? Is `linkText` a reserved keyword or something now? (All I know is that [it wasn’t in 2008](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/g-link-vs-g-createLink-in-a-g-each-td1338916.html).)
2. Why am I getting a “nullable” error rather than one for “blank”? They are different errors. I have a custom message in `messages.properties` for this, but even given that Grails does not want to use that right now, I would expect it to be giving me its `default.blank.message` (“`Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be blank`”).

No. 1 on that list is the most concerning to me, but I really don’t see why Grails is treating this field any differently from all of the other three `Strings` in the class in the first place.

Comment: Check if you get the same error with item.properties = params or bindData(item, params)

Comment: Have you tried to change the attribute name to something else to rule out that the attribute name is what's causing the issue?

Comment: I can only comment on question 2: When you set an attribute to "blank:false" this implies that also a "nullable:false" constraint is applied automatically.

Comment: @uchamp `item` is actually being saved inside a service, so `bindData()` is not available. But I tried it with `item.properties = params` and got the same result: all of the other properties were set, but `linkText` was left with `null`. Thanks though.

Comment: @c_maker I am using Liquibase in this project and making any sort of changes to a domain class (and thus to the database) entails far more effort (along with Pain and Frustration) than I could be persuaded to take on at this point. So I actually created a separate app to try to isolate the problem; I gave it the class with the `String` properties and it was completely fine with `linkText`. I am thinking that it must be a separate app-specific problem having to do with how I set up this domain class and related persistence code.

Comment: @david I did not know that. But even so I have had `String` properties for which I set `blank: false` but left off the `nullable` constraint entirely, and when I set off the validation errors for them they would give me the `item.blank` message I mentioned earlier. This one `String` is behaving differently for whatever odd reason (given the same constraint — `blank` — set to false, and omitting the `nullable` constraint completely).

Comment: @david: Can you point me to the documentation on this pls?: "When you set an attribute to "blank:false" this implies that also a "nullable:false" constraint is applied automatically."

Comment: @c_maker sorry mixed this up. Correct: by default there is an "nullable:false" constraint, if it is not explicitely set to true (http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Constraints/nullable.html)

Comment: @ebenezer, like yourself I was unable to reproduce this issue in a fresh project. Can you try with a non params map? Just create something yourself and then try instantiating your item using the custom map.

Comment: @uchamp Wow. You win. :) I just tried that again using a new `Map` called (appropriately for the purposes of this experiment) `foo`; I gave it the params coming out of the `params` `Map`, and when I created the item using `new Item(foo)` it saved without any problems at all. File this under “Hmm.”

Comment: hmmmmm! I guess I should post this as an answer and get some bounty :)

Comment: @uchamp Indeed! At least it will get accepted. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I tried this in a fresh project and could not reproduce the issue.

For #1: I would try a couple different things:

1. A new map with all key/value pairs (not a clone of params) and try instantiating my Item using this custom map. Just to confirm if it's the domain/constraints or the params map that is causing the unexpected behaviour.
2. A clone of params and then use it for instantiating.

If it works fine in both the cases then I'd take a very close look on my actual params map and compare it with the working clone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe #2 is happening because:

- "By default, all domain class properties are not nullable (i.e. they have an implicit nullable: false constraint)." (Quoted from [Grails Validation documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html)).
- I suspect that in the order of validation, grails checks the nullability constraint **first** for attributes. (Need to verify this, however)

I suspect these are the reasons why you are getting the null constraint and not the blank one. 
I believe that if you set the linkText property to be nullable: true, then you would start getting the error message for the blank constraint. Now I tried this and it is not behaving how I expect it to.

For the following domain class:

```
class Item {
  String linkText

  static constraints = {
    linkText nullable: true, blank: false
}
```

And attempting to save it like so:

```
def item= new Item(linkText: "")
item.save()
```

Grails is happily saving the item with a blank value. However, if I take out the nullable: true constraint, it complains about the blank value.

Comment: Huh. Well now that is bizarre… Thanks for trying that though.